# Global.asax Application_BeginRequest()

Tags: c#, asp.net

looking for an expert opinion on this, I have tried all and the only thing that works for me is this

Global.asax

```
<pre>
    if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Items.Count>0)  
    {  
       //- This is a class that validate authenticate user. 
       if (!UserIsValidated)  
       {  
         //- Validate the user here, done validated do not fire anymore
       }  
    }
</pre>
```

what I am trying to accomplish here is that when the user is authenticated that the class
`UserIsValidated` do not fire any more, as of now it is only firing when user is logging in for authentication, when the user is logging out of the application and when the user request a file for download.

My question is, is there a better approach for the class `UserIsValidated` only firing when the user is authenticating his/her login access?

I do not like my application to have lots of working threads.

TIA

Comment: `UserIsValidated` doesn't look like a class, it's a Boolean property. To answer your question, you can check the url of the current request, if it is a login url then you go ahead with `UserIsValidated` check else do nothing